# Weakness in Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Solving a minimization problem in version 13 on Windows 10, I obtain

```
Maximize[{Sin[x + Sin[x]] + Sin[x - Sin[x]] + (Pi/2 - 2)*Sin[Sin[x]], 
x >= 0 && x < 2*Pi}, x]//FullSimplify
```

> `{2 Cos[Sin[Root[{Pi Cos[Sin[#]] - 4 Sin[Sin[#]] Sin[#]& ,  0.9033391107665128473590217051048716426220.300104378161908}]]]\ Sin[Root[{Pi Cos[Sin[#]] - 4 Sin[Sin[#]] Sin[#]& ,  0.9033391107665128473590217051048716426220.300104378161908}]] + 1/2 (-4 + \[Pi]) Sin[Sin[Root[{Pi Cos[Sin[#]] - 4 Sin[Sin[#]] Sin[#]& ,  0.9033391107665128473590217051048716426220.300104378161908}]]]\ , {x -> Root[{Pi Cos[Sin[#]] - 4 Sin[Sin[#]] Sin[#]& ,  0.9033391107665128473590217051048716426220.300104378161908}]}}`

which is not very useful as a symbolic solution.

Along with that, Mathematica is able to find an optimal solution in a closed form
and this is its achievement. Indeed,

```
Maximize[Sin[x+Sin[x]]+Sin[x-Sin[x]]+(Pi/2-2)*Sin[Sin[x]],x]
```

> `{1/2 (-2 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[2] \[Pi]), {x -> -47 \[Pi] - ArcSin[\[Pi]/4]}}`

Since the objective function has `2*Pi` as its minimal positive period,
the same value is taken at

```
Mod[-47 \[Pi] - ArcSin[\[Pi]/4], 2*Pi]
```

> `\[Pi] - ArcSin[\[Pi]/4]`

```
N[%]
```

> `2.23825`

and

```
Plot[Sin[x + Sin[x]] + Sin[x - Sin[x]] + (Pi/2 - 2)*Sin[Sin[x]], {x,0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]
confirms it.

How to obtain `{1/2 (-2 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[2] \[Pi]), {x -> Pi-ArcSin[Pi/4]}}` programmatically?

Comment: BTW, `FunctionPeriod[
 Sin[x + Sin[x]] + Sin[x - Sin[x]] + (Pi/2 - 2)*Sin[Sin[x]], x]` performs `0`. One more a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = Sin[x + Sin[x]] + Sin[x - Sin[x]] + (Pi/2 - 2)*Sin[Sin[x]];

{max, arg} = 
 Maximize[{expr, 0 <= x < 2 Pi}, x] // FullSimplify // Quiet
```

[image]

[`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) will have a much easier time if you simplify the expression first.

```
expr2 = Simplify[expr, 0 <= x < 2 Pi]

(* 2 Cos[Sin[x]] Sin[x] + 1/2 (-4 + π) Sin[Sin[x]] *)

{max2, arg2} = Maximize[{expr2, 0 <= x < 2 Pi}, x] // FullSimplify

(* {(-2 + π)/Sqrt[2], {x -> ArcSin[π/4]}} *)

max - max2 // N[#, 20] & // Quiet

(* 0.*10^-69 *)

(x /. arg) - (x /. arg2) // N[#, 20] & // Quiet

(* 0.*10^-70 *)
```

**EDIT:** Likewise with [`FunctionPeriod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionPeriod.html)

```
FunctionPeriod[expr2, x]

(* 2 π *)
```

Comment: `Quiet` is not needed: Mathematica produces a warning, not an error.

Comment: Quiet should only be used for warnings and never for error messages. It removes the clutter of the warning after it has been reviewed and determined to be of no import.

Comment: Also `expr2 = Simplify[expr]` works.